# Terraform Azure setup self hosted gateway hostname

Tags: azure, terraform, gateway, azure-rm, apim

How is it possible to provision Hostnames for self hosted gateways in Azure API Management? Terraform shows how to add a new gateway but not how to configure the hostname:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_gateway

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Custom domain name for a self-hosted API Management Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-configure-custom-domain-gateway) is not yet supported in Terraform azurerm provider

Here is [opened GitHub PR](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/17166) to implement this feature in Terraform